# Pandas to_datetime method

Tags: python

Convert the following date strings into datetime objects: datelist = ['14-Sep-2017', '9-Sep-2017'].
Note: Use the to_datetime method of pandas.
Capture the result in the variable 'dates_to_be_searched' and print it.

Answer (score 0):

This will generate a Dataframe with the strings and convert using the `to_datetime` method:

```py
dates_to_be_searched = ['14-Sep-2017', '9-Sep-2017']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': dates_to_be_searched})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
print(df)
```

Outputs:

```
        Date
0 2017-09-14
1 2017-09-09
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
import pandas as pd
datelist = ['14-Sep-2017', '9-Sep-2017']
dates_to_be_searched = [pd.to_datetime(x) for x in datelist]
```